# Beaglebone tracing a device driver using a device tree file

Tags: kernel, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack, can-bus

I'm trying to modify the device driver of the CBB-Serial beaglebone cape. I want to change a part of how it handles the CAN protocol's CRC check for a school project. My overall goal is to modify the CRC computation of one node and observe the reaction of other nodes on the CAN bus.

I've found the device overlay for the cape [here](https://github.com/lgxlogic/CBB-Serial/blob/master/overlay/cape-CBB-Serial-r01.dts). How can I efficiently search through the kernel to find where the pins dcan1_rx and dcan1_tx are being read and written to? I'm hoping this will lead me to the CRC computation.

Answer (score 1):

The CBB-Serial cape doesn't use its own driver - the Beaglebone uses this driver for the CAN modules: https://github.com/beagleboard/linux/blob/4.1/drivers/net/can/m_can/m_can.c